# Project of WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to make a WPF application to simulate and visualize deterministic finite automaton. I made c# library for simulation and now I want to use it in my WPF app. I want it to work like this:

**MainWindow** shows and user can specify automaton parameters: number of states, alphabet, accept states, starting state then when user click on generate button new **dialog window** shows.

In new **dialog window** should be an array of integers editable by user, this will represent transition function. The size of array will vary basing on states and alphabet symbols number.

When user click OK button **dialog window** will be closed and new object of `DeterministicFiniteAutomaton` class will be created.

After that user can click on `Visualize` button and new **visualization window** should show for visualizing work of created object.

My questions are:

1) How should I pass states number and alphabet symbols to dialog window?

2) How should I get table of ints edited by user from dialog window?

3) Where I should store objects of `DeterministicFiniteAutomaton` class so I can assign one automaton to one `visualization window`?

Comment: An answer to this question would practically require us to write the entire application for you. Are you trying to trick us into working for free? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The constructor of **dialog window** can accept parameters. Pass whatever you want from **MainWindow** to **dialog window**.

```
DialogWindow dialogwindow = new DialogWindow(params); 
dialogwindow.ShowDialog();
```

2) In DialogWindow, expose the array of ints by a `Property`.

```
public int[] EditedValues { get; private set;}
```

and access it in **MainWindow** like

```
int[] editedValues = dialogwindow.EditedValues;
```

3) same as 2), in DialogWindow, expose `DeterministicFiniteAutomaton` as a Property.